# functions structure definitions

Tags: scheme, racket

i am trying to make the function

`author-book`

which given a book, produces the author of the book. heres the data i've created for this-

```
(define-struct audiobook ( title author length-in-minutes voice-person))

(define-struct ebook ( title author size-in-kolobytes symbol ))

(define-struct hardcover (title author number-of-pages genre ))

(define audiobook1 (make-audiobook "The Hunger Games" "Suzanne Collins" "50 minutes" "David Larrson"))
(define audiobook2 (make-audiobook "Catching Fire" "Suzanne Collins" "55 minutes" "David Larrson"))
(define audiobook3 (make-audiobook "Mockingjay" "Suzanne Collins" "40 minutes" "David Larrson"))

(define ebook1 (make-ebook "Divergent" "Veronica Roth" "100000kbs" 'Kindle))
(define ebook2 (make-ebook "Dracula" "Bram Stocker " "134000kbs" 'Ebook))
(define ebook3 (make-ebook "Jane Eyre" "Charlotte Brontë " "400000kbs" 'IPad))

(define hardcover1 (make-hardcover "Pursued" "Jud White" "100000kbs" "Crime"))
(define hardcover2 (make-hardcover "Private Berlin" "James Patterson" "100000kbs" "Suspense"))
(define hardcover3 (make-hardcover "Francona" "Terry Francona" "100000kbs" "Sports"))
```

I've tried

```
(define (author-of-book n)
        (audiobook-author n))
```

this gives me the author of only the audiobook. is there a way i can  get the author of the rest without having to write three seperate functions? (like ebook-author...)

Comment: Have you already read this?: http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-10.html#node_sec_7.2 (if you're using the first edition of your textbook), or http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_one.html#%28part._sec~3adesign-itemization%29 (if you're using the second edition)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another possible implementation, just a little bit shorter than @jozefg's answer (tested and working):

```
(define (author-of-book b)
  ((cond [(audiobook? b) audiobook-author]
         [(hardcover? b) hardcover-author]
         [(ebook? b)     ebook-author])
   b))
```

The `cond` expression returns the correct procedure to use in each case, and the one that gets selected is applied to `b`. For example:

```
(author-of-book audiobook1)
=> "Suzanne Collins"

(author-of-book ebook1)
=> "Veronica Roth"

(author-of-book hardcover1)
=> "Jud White"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did try something like before I asked, but it kept saying "function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but found a part".  it says the same thing with these functions. i cant seem to find out the problem.

Comment: @Josh are you sure it isn't a typo? the above code works for me. Maybe  it's because of the language, which one are you using?

Comment: i am using beginning student

Comment: @Josh well, that explains it. Try this instead: `(define (author-of-book b)
  (cond ((audiobook? b) (audiobook-author b))
        ((hardcover? b) (hardcover-author b))
        ((ebook? b) (ebook-author b))))`

Answer (score 2):

You can pretty easily check to see what type of book it is and then go from there

```
(define (author-of-book b)
    (cond 
        [(audiobook? b) (audiobook-author b)]
        [(hardcover? b) (hardcover-author b)]
        [(ebook? b)     (ebook-author b)]))
```

This is a little verbose but nothing too bad.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the code was wrong when you first posted it. @Soegaard fixed it in his edit, you were missing the actual function application

Answer (score 1):

You have three different structs which share a common substructure: all three have a `title` and `author`. You can encode this sharing in the struct definitions:

```
(define-struct book (title author))

(define-struct (audiobook book) (length-in-minutes voice-person))
(define-struct (ebook book) (size-in-kolobytes symbol))
(define-struct (hardcover book) (number-of-pages genre))
```

We've cleaned up the field duplication in the three structs, and as an added bonus, we can simply use `book-author` to access the author field for any of the three kinds of books.

```
> (book-author audiobook1)
"Suzanne Collins"
> (book-author ebook1)
"Veronica Roth"
> (book-author hardcover1)
"Jud White"
```